# IC for clocked nor RS latch

Tags: latch

Does anybody know if I can find an IC of a NOR RS latch?  It has to have a clock and does not have to have any other functions such as clear or preset.

EDIT 1:  It could be a D Flip Flop gated but internally it has to work with an RS Nor logic not JK logic.

Comment: Your requirements sound confusing. In my mind a latch had D and C inputs, hence it is called a D-latch. R and S are commonly found on an asynchronous element. Maybe give the truth table for the element you want?

Comment: Here's a list of all the standard logic cells available: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits see if it has what you need.

Comment: Why does it specifically have to be a NOR RS? Surely a quad 2 input NAND chip (eg 7400) would give you the same basic logic. http://images.slideplayer.com/13/3942553/slides/slide_22.jpg

Comment: Your requirements are strange, as @WoutervanOoijen said. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve. Is it a real technical problem or is it some kind of school/university exercise? If you need that exact combination of requirements for some project you are building, you can build it from basic parts (build an RS latch from two NORs, then prepend AND gates with a common input gated from an edge detector circuit whose input would be the clock). Funny though.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a circuit functioning as you ask, since RS flip-flops are asynchronous and do not need an edge. However, what I *think* you want can be done with one and a half 7474/74HC74/74LS74 packages.

A SR NOR flip-flop looks like

[image: schematic]
The first two flip-flops store the SR inputs, and the third IS a SR flip-flop.

If both outputs are low the output does not change, and if either goes high the state of the output reflects the input. And, of course, both inputs high is not permitted.

It's easy to add an edge function.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsIioA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first two flip-flops act as D FFs and store the input values on the edge, and the third IS a SR FF.